# Sveltekit hook locals not clearing on redirect

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a `/signin` page which sets a cookie and redirect to the root page:

```js
cookies.set('token', 'Bearer token', {
    path: '/',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24
});
throw redirect(303, '/');
```

Then a hook, `hooks.server.ts` that uses that cookie to fetch a user and add it to `locals` for the rest of the app to use:

```js
export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const accessToken = event.cookies.get('token')
    payload = verifyToken(accessToken)
    sessionUser = fetchUser(payload)
    event.locals.user = sessionUser;
    return await resolve(event);
}
```

This is all fine, can use the `user` object on any page.

What I'm having problems with is the `/signout`, deleting the cookies.

I made a simple `signout/+page.server.ts` and put the logic in the `load`:

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ cookies }) => {
    cookies.delete('token', {
        path: '/'
    });

    throw redirect(307, '/');
};
```

It deletes the cookie but the user is still in the `locals` object, until I refresh the page (F5), then the hook runs again and it's gone from `locals`.

How do I get the hook to run on redirect? Or clear the `locals`?

Comment: Have you tried including `invalidateAll`? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#rerunning-load-functions-manual-invalidation